# How are object properties implemented in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I had an array with a large amount of values that I was iterating over to find a specific value like this:

```
function haveValue(value) {
  for(var index in arr) {
    var prop = arr[index];
    if(prop === value) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

But it occurred to me that I could possibly perform this lookup much more quickly by using an object:

```
function haveValue(value) {
  return typeof obj[value] !== 'undefined';
}
```

However, I have not seen much of an improvement in performance after doing this. So I'm wondering, how are object properties stored in Javascript/Node.js? Are they basically iterated over in order to find, the same as an array? I thought they might be implemented using a hash table or something.

Comment: if `arr` is an `Array` you should use a `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length;i++)` loop, not a `for in`

Comment: @A.Duff - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: Property access is going to be highly optimized. No engine would iterate over all the keys to find a matching one. I suggest if you try this will one million values you'll find a massive difference.

Comment: [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) ?

Comment: How many elements is "large" and how often are you calling `hasValue`?

Answer (score 0):

You've asked about iliterating through an array and if using an object would give you better performance, however you are using a `for in` loop for an array, and the perfromance might be better increased using a `for` loop or es6 includes method.

If `arr` is an array and you only want to check if it contains a value, you could use the es6 `includes()` method ([docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes))

```
function haveValue(value) {
  return (arr.includes(value));
}
```

N.B. you'll need to check if your target browsers support it and shim/pollyfill if not.

if you dont want to use es6 then you can loop with a `for` loop

```
function haveValue(value) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] === value) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

in your example you are using a `for in` loop which is really for objects not arrays. the `for` loop should give you better perf when used on arrays

while the size of the object might effect perf when using a string to find a value in a object (like a hashmap), the effect might be insignificant as js engines will be internally optimised.

check this [jspef](http://jsperf.com/obj-loop-internally), selecting the first of last property of an object doesnt really effect perfromance. (obviously that effect may scale)

Comment: How exactly does this answer the question about objects?

Comment: while perf might not be the main reason, it's certainly a strong one http://jsperf.com/forloops3